# Change mountpoint of docker volume to a custom directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to have a Docker Volume that mounts to a container. This volume would need to be somewhere other than the default location of volumes, preferably somewhere on the Desktop. This is because I am running a web server and would like some directories to be editable by something like VSCode so I don't always have to go inside the container to edit a file. I am not going to be using Docker Compose and instead will be using a Docker File for the container. The functionality I'm going for is the following equivalent of Docker Compose, but in a Dockerfile or through `docker run`, whichever is easiest to accomplish:

```
volumes:
  - <local-dir>:<container-dir>
```

This directory will need to be editable LIVE and using the Dockerfile *ADD* command will not suffice, because after building, the image gets put into a tar archive and cannot be accessed after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount a directory from your host inside your container when you launch the docker container, using `-v` or `--volume`

```
docker run -v /path/to/desktop/some-dir:/container-dir/path <docker-image>
```

Volumes specified in the Dockerfile, as you exemplified, will automatically create those volumes under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` every time a container is launched from that image, but it is **NOT** recommended have these volumes altered by non-Docker processes.

Comment: This worked, but cannot accept relative file names, which is not really ideal, but I can deal with it.

Comment: @AntoniosP., you can use `$(pwd)` or `%cd%` for Linux respectively Windows, if you want to refer to the working directory. E.g.: `docker run -v $(pwd)/static/whatever:/container-dir/path ...`

Comment: Great, this helped a lot!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

#### with this solution you can move even A live container to new partition:

1. Add a configuration file to tell the docker daemon what is the location of the data directory
   Using your preferred text editor add a file named daemon.json under the directory /etc/docker. The file should have this content:

```
{ 
   "data-root": "/path/to/your/docker" 
}
```

3. Copy the current data directory to the new one

```
sudo rsync -aP /var/lib/docker/ /path/to/your/docker
```

4. Rename the old docker directory

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.old
```

5. Restart the docker daemon

```
sudo service docker start
```

resource: https://www.guguweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-move-docker-data-directory-to-another-location-on-ubuntu/